# Injector error in Angular JS with Jhipster

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jhipster

I have an problem to import "oi.select" in my jhipster project.
My controller js file :

```
  (function() {
        'use strict';

        angular
            .module('myApp')
            .controller('UserProfileDialogController', UserProfileDialogController);

        UserProfileDialogController.$inject = ['$timeout', '$scope', '$stateParams', '$uibModalInstance', 'entity', 'UserProfile', 'MdmEnumeration','oi.select'];

        function UserProfileDialogController ($timeout, $scope, $stateParams, $uibModalInstance, entity, UserProfile, MdmEnumeration,oiSelect) {

} ....
```

I have already inject in my index.html :

- `<script src="bower_components/oi.select/dist/select-tpls.min.js"></script>`
- `<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/oi.select/dist/select.min.css">`

I get the followin error :

angular.js:13550 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: oi.selectProvider <- oi.select <- UserProfileDialogController

Any ideas ?

Comment: From what I saw in the oi.select documentation it is a directive. Have you tried adding the dependency to your module instead of your controller? https://github.com/tamtakoe/oi.select `angular.module('myApp', ['oi.select']);`

Comment: yes i tried and i get the following error : 

`Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module eProductApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider`

Comment: That seems to be a different issue, related to the ui-router. Do you use that? See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: i solved this. I have a file : app.module.js which contains all modules to inject in the app. I add "oi.select" and it works.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe you should delete your question as I doubt it will help anyone as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this. I have a file : app.module.js which contains all modules to inject in the app. I add "oi.select" and it works. Thanks for your help